# What is the difference between bindingProvider.getBindings and bindingProvider.getBindingAccessors?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to make a custom bindingProvider, and I see from [the source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/bindingProvider.js) that it should have a `getBindings` method and a `getBindingAccessors` method. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: You will want to implement `nodeHasBindings` and a `getBindingAccessors` functions if you are working against Knockout 3.0+. `getBindings` is still supported for backwards compatibility with KO 2+ code. With `getBindingsAccessors` you should return binding name / accessor pairs. An accessor is a function that returns the value of the binding.

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for. Please post a proper answer that I can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to implement `nodeHasBindings` and `getBindingAccessors` functions if you are working against Knockout 3.0+. `getBindings` is still supported for backwards compatibility with KO 2+ code. With `getBindingsAccessors` you should return binding name / accessor pairs. An accessor is a function that returns the value of the binding.